# Drupal views get fields after filters without html markup

Tags: views

I have a question about Drupal 7 and Views. Let's assume that I have views where I extract 2 articles ordered by post date. I want to extract only title and trimmed introduction (trim configured in field settings in view)

Now I would like to extract this data programmatically without HTML markup. So the result will be similar to this:

```
array(
    0 => array(
        'title' => 'Lorem ipsum',
        'introduction' => 'Lorem ipsum dolar solor...'
    ),
    1 => array(
        'title' => 'Lorem ipsum2',
        'introduction' => 'Lorem ipsum2 dolar solor...'
    )
)
```

Is it possible to extract such information from views? 
I tried to do something like this:

```
$view = views_get_view('view_name');
$view->set_display('display_id');
$view->execute();
$data = $view->result;
```

But `$data` contain two elements with full nodes (all additional fields that I don't want to grab from database)

In addition for instance introduction is grabbed fully (must be trimmed somewhere in PHP).

Is it possible to do something like this:

```
$view->applyFilters(); //Like trim etc
$data = $view->getResults(); //return title + trimmed introduction but without HTML markup
```

Do You have any tips how to solve this problem? Is it possible for instance to pass template that will be rendered (where I could display only raw result without any HTML tags) or something?

Any help would be appreciated:)

Comment: what do you indent to do with this result?

Comment: Anything, for instance return it via ajax as JSON

Comment: Have you tried using strip html and trim on the views page when adding the fields?

Comment: Could You explain it a little more? Or maybe I don't clear it up enough. When views is rendered normally for instance `$view->preview()` it will generate something like this: `<div class="views-field views-field-field-introduction"><div class="field-content">Lorem ipsum...</div></div>`

I don't want the outer html i just want Lorem ipsum...

Comment: I don't get it - is there HTML in your fields, in their data in database, and you want to strip it, or something adds HTML formatting and you want to disable it?

Comment: @Mołot Second thing - disable formatting around record. `<div class="views-field..` is added while rendering. It's not saved in database. I want to strip this tags on every field

Comment: Have you looked into writing a views style plugin? That might be the cleanest way to solve your issue. https://api.drupal.org/api/views/plugins!views_plugin_style.inc/group/views_style_plugins/7

Comment: @AlfredArmstrong thanks a lot! Your tip with views style plugin was very good. after `$view->execute()` execute `$data = $view->style_plugin->render_fields($view->result);` and under `$data` I have array of filtered results without HTML code:)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After suggestion from AlfredArmstrong I checked plugin style docs.
To get filtered data without rendering html template simply do:

```
 $data = $view->style_plugin->render_fields($view->result);
```

Under `$data` will be array of filtered fields from view.

Comment: I feel like I've been searching all my life for this answer. THANK YOU!

Answer (score 0):

In your fields settings, open "Style settings:

[image: Screenshot]

Customize HTMLs, setting them both to *-None-* .

If that's not enough, Look at the right column. Section *Other*. Click on *Theme information* and provide custom tpl.php file for your field.

Comment: That's nice, it's actually give results without extra html markup. But is it possible to do it programmaticaly like in the code in my question? To get array of data instead of rendered view?

Comment: @Astaz3l If you only want a query result, why don't you query directly? You can easily "steal" query from views.

Comment: True, I can get the query directly but for instance it won't return trimmed content - it's done in PHP, not it MySQL query.

Comment: @Astaz3l have you tried to (ab)use [views_get_views_as_options](https://api.drupal.org/api/views/views.module/function/views_get_views_as_options/7)?